# Promise.all inside an asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have 2 codes

1 code

```
async function foo() {
    const result1 = asyncFunc1();
    const result2 = asyncFunc2();
    return [result1, result2];
}
```

2 code

```
async function foo() {
    const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([
        asyncFunc1(),
        asyncFunc2(),
    ]);
return [result1,result2];
}
```

question
Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: If there were `await`s in the first example it would be series, rather than parallel.

Comment: you didn't use `await` in the first example, so you are not waiting for the completion of the async functions, thus `result1` and `result2` will be equal to promises instead of result values

Comment: @OlivierBoissé means 1 code synchronously 2 code asynchronously ?

Answer (score 2):

As the comments state, you did not await the function calls in the first snippet, so you will get promises as return values. However if you used await, one major difference is that in the first snippet, `asyncFunc2` isn't *executed* until `asyncFunc1` is resolved (assuming you use `await`). Whereas, in the second snippet, `asyncFunc2` is executed right after `asyncFunc1` regardless of whether it has resolved.

Promise.all will return the results in the order in which you pass the functions.

See docs for [Promise.All](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and [Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Comment: To be clear, the first snippet is not currently using await, so the snippets are the same apart from the first snippet not waiting for the results.

Comment: @FINDarkside yes great catch, updated.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, there is essentially no difference in the two, other than the fact that you have not awaited the results from the two async functions, so you're gonna end up with just the promise objects.  Async functions don't await scoped promises / async code automatically, they just allow you to use the await keyword, which is just stopping the execution until the underlying promise is resolved.

Here's an attempt to illustrate those differences.

What's important to note is that the returned values for the first function are not 1, 2 as would be expected.

```
const asyncFunc = (a) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {   
      setTimeout(() => resolve(a), 1000);
  })
}

const asyncFunc1 = () => asyncFunc(1);
const asyncFunc2 = () => asyncFunc(2);

async function foo() {
    const result1 = asyncFunc1();
    const result2 = asyncFunc2();
    return JSON.stringify({ result1, result2 });
}

async function foo2() {
    return [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([
        asyncFunc1(),
        asyncFunc2(),
    ]);
}


(async () =>{
    const el = document.createElement('div');
    el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(await foo()));
    el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(await foo2()));
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(el);
})();


// {"result1":{},"result2":{}} 1,2
```

Here's a fiddle to play around with; [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8bfn26oy/3/).

Comment: *compilation* is definetly the wrong word here, did you mean *execution* ?

Comment: yes, definitely meant _execution_.  thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Just find it out! Here is a snippet that shows all major differences:

```js
const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

async function one() {
  console.log("1 one called");
  await timer(2000);
  console.log("1 one done");
}

async function two() {
  console.log("2 two called");
  await timer(1000);
  console.log("2 two done");
  // throw new Error; // Uncomment to see another interesting behaviour
}

(async function main() {
  const startParallel = Date.now();
  await Promise.all([one(), two()]);
  console.log(`parallel done, took ${Date.now() - startParallel}`);

  const startSerial = Date.now();
  await one();
  await two();
  console.log(`serial done, took ${Date.now() - startSerial}`);
})();
```